# Does clojure have identifier macros?

Tags: clojure, macros

In other words, is there any way to trigger macro expansion on forms that don't look like `(MACRO arg* ...)`.

To give a hypothetical example:

```
(defmacro my-var
  (do (printf "Using my-var!\n") 42))
(+ my-var 1) ;; Should print & return 43
```

What I really want to do is call `macroexpand` on a term with free variables. I want to these free variables should have special meaning during macro expansion, but should go back to "normal" afterward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This facility currently exists in Clojure as one of the features of the Clojure Contrib library [tools.macro](https://github.com/clojure/tools.macro). The relevant tools.macro macros are `defsymbolmacro`, `with-symbol-macros` and `symbol-macrolet` – here's a `symbol-macrolet` example from the README (as found on the tip of the master branch right now):

```
(symbol-macrolet [def foo]
  (def def def))
```

> expands to (def def foo)

`symbol-macrolet` is used to introduce lexically scoped symbol macros, while `defsymbolmacro` introduces symbol macros to be applied inside any `with-symbol-macros` blocks (doing away with `with-symbol-macros` would only be possible with support from the Clojure compiler itself).

AFAIK, some version of `symbol-macrolet` has been a planned feature for inclusion in Clojure's compiler itself for quite a while; it is expected that when and if it lands, it will likely be called `letmacro`. There's no concrete public timeline for that, though, and it is certainly not guaranteed to land at all.

The names that tools.macro uses are inspired by Common Lisp, where the relevant macros are known as [`define-symbol-macro`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_1.htm) and [`symbol-macrolet`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_symbol.htm). Since this is a standard compiler feature in CL, symbol macros introduced with `define-symbol-macro` are actually applied globally without assistance from any helper macros.

Comment: Interesting, I was using a transient map as a work-around, but the library seems to do the same thing (with the `macro-symbols` table).

Comment: Yes, it has to maintain a macro expander environment, and it uses a dynamic Var holding a map for that. In use it feels like a natural expansion of Clojure's built-in macro capabilities. (I suppose some quirks are possible, since the expansion process for the bodies of the more interesting macros is, of necessity, driven from outside the compiler, but I thought it felt pretty smooth.) In any case, the map is only used at macro-expansion time – any symbol macros' expansions are interpolated into the expressions in which they occur during expansion in the way one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no, Clojure does not have this feature.

With the exception of the reader macros such as quote `'`, syntax-quote `, dispatch `#`, etc. which do expand outside the function argument position, you cannot add macros that expand in this position.

Reader literals are slightly related in that you can define literal syntax that will be converted into a data structure at read time, though these cannot be used as variables like you are describing.

The auto-gensym feature of the syntax-quote reader macro has a little of this flavor though in a much more limited way.